# Difference between Executor and ExecutorCompletionservice in java

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

As the question title itself says what is the difference between Executors and ExecutorCompletionService classes in java?

I am new to the Threading,so if any one can explain with a piece of code, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Suppose you had a set of tasks `A, B, C, D, E` and you want to execute each of them asynchronously in an `Executor` and process the results 1 by 1 as they complete.

With an `Executor`, you would do so like this:

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
futures.add(executorService.submit(A));
futures.add(executorService.submit(B));
futures.add(executorService.submit(C));
futures.add(executorService.submit(D));
futures.add(executorService.submit(E));

//This loop must process the tasks in the order they were submitted: A, B, C, D, E
for (Future<?> future:futures) {
    ? result = future.get();
    // Some processing here
}
```

The problem with this method is that there is no guarantee that task `A` will complete first. Thus, it is possible that the main thread will be blocking idly waiting for task `A` to complete when it could be processing the result of another task (say task `B`). Result processing latency could be reduced by using an `ExecutorCompletionService`.

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
futures.add(executorCompletionService.submit(A));
futures.add(executorCompletionService.submit(B));
futures.add(executorCompletionService.submit(C));
futures.add(executorCompletionService.submit(D));
futures.add(executorCompletionService.submit(E));

//This for loop will process the tasks in the order they are completed,  
//regardless of submission order
for (int i=0; i<futures.size(); i++) {
    ? result = executorCompletionService.take().get();
    // Some processing here
}
```

So, in essence, `ExecutorCompletionService` could be used to squeeze out a little more efficiency when the order of processing task results does not matter.

One important thing to note though. The implementation of ExecutorCompletionService contains a queue of results. If `take` or `poll` are not called to drain that queue, a memory leak will occur. Some people use the `Future` returned by `submit` to process results and this is NOT correct usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for your support. The example and explanation is crystal clear.

Comment: Such an amazing answer and got only 18 votes so far. This just makes me sad. That infant looks so cute in your hands.

Answer (score 3):

An `ExecutorCompletionService` will simply wrap and delegate to a normal `Executor` and offer convenience methods for retrieving the most recently completed tasks.

The api has a few examples that should get you going

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html