# Is there an ExecutorService on blocking thread?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

Is there an `ExecutorService` that allows an existing thread to perform the executions instead of spawning new threads? Bonus if it’s a ScheduledExecutor. Most executors spawn worker threads to do the execution, but I want the worker thread to be an existing thread that I’m on. Here's the API that I imagine:

```
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    Runnable r = executor.take();
    r.run();
}
```

This is similar to the way that SWT and JavaFX allow the main thread to dispatch events, as opposed to Swing, which requires its own event dispatch thread to be spawned to handle events.

Motivation: I currently have lots of places where a thread spawn a new executor and then just calls awaitTermination() to wait for it to finish. I’d like to save some resources and keep the stack traces from being split in two.

Note that I don’t want an executor that runs tasks in `execute(Runnable)`’s caller threads, which is what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941617/executorservice-which-runs-tasks-in-calling-thread) and Guava’s [`MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#sameThreadExecutor()) do.

Comment: Are you asking for [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29)? Or maybe [`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29) ?

Comment: How does `take()` indicate that the answer to the hypothetical `Executor#isTerminated()` predicate changed to false after you saw it return true?

Comment: @seh Presumably, `isTerminated` reads some `volatile` variable that can be changed by another thread asking it to terminate. This is a question on concurrency after all :3

Comment: That implementation detail does not address my design question. The loop is crippled by a relying on a *check-then-act* protocol. The truth indicated by `(SomeKindOf)Executor#isTerminated()` can change before the call to `(SomeKindOf)Executor#take()`. Does `take()` return null then, or throw `InterruptedException`? It needs a codomain wider than just `Runnable` to indicate that it was called on after the executor had been terminated.

Comment: @seh Termination is different than shutdown. Look at [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). There are two values: shutdown (which controls whether or not tasks are accepted) and terminated (which returns true if there are jobs remaining to be executed. So yes, once the job queue is empty, the shutdown process would interrupt all threads in its thread pool and `take` would throw an `InterruptedException`. Adding the isTerminated check would allow the thread to terminate normally without relying on exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Most executors from java.util.concurrent behave exactly as you supposed. Some spawn additional threads when there are too many tasks, but usually they can be configured to set a limit.

To exploit such a behaviour, do not start new executor each time - use the same executor. To wait for a set of tasks to finish, use [invokeAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29), or [submit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and then [future.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you want is control over the creation of new threads, such as name, daemon-status, etc. Use a `ThreadFactory`:

```
public class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
        Thread t = new Thread(runnable, "MyThreadName");
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    }
}
```

This allows you to control thread creation so that the execution happens in threads that *you* manufacture instead of some default thread from a default `ThreadFactory`.

Then to use it, all of the methods in `Executors` take a `ThreadFactory`:

```
Executors.newExecutorOfSomeKind(new MyThreadFactory());
```

**Edit:** I see what you mean now. Unfortunately, the behavior of all `Executor` implementations (as far as I'm aware) is to create new threads to run the task, except the `sameThreadExecutor` you mentioned. Without going through the `Thread` objects that are creating executors just to execute one task (which is a horrible design -- see comments for what I mean by this), there's no easy way to accomplish what you want. I would recommend changing the code to use a single `Executor` with something like an `ExecutorCompletionService` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758020/difference-between-executor-and-executorcompletionservice-in-java)) or use a fork/join pattern. Fork/join is made easier in Java 7 (see [this Java trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)). For pre-Java 7 code, read up on the counting [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) in Java (and [in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)).

Comment: Objection to "horrible design". No one Executor implementation from  java.util.concurrent creates new thread for each task.

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov See Cached Thread Pool - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29.  If you have many long running tasks there is a possibility each task will have its own thread.

Comment: @John Vint Possibility, but not a rule. If it can it would reuse existing thread, that is, their thread's run() method does contain the loop over task queue, as TS proposed.

Comment: Right, but to say "No one Executor implementation from java.util.concurrent creates new thread for each task" is misleading and I know `newCachedThreadPool` used naively has completely killed systems.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov @JohnVint To be clear, by "horrible design", I meant having each thread create an executor to complete a set of tasks only to destroy that executor later is poor design. From the question: "I currently have lots of places where a thread spawn a new executor and then just calls awaitTermination() to wait for it to finish." From what I understand, he has his thread 1) create an executor, 2) submit jobs, 3) call terminate, 4) call awaitTerminate. Instead of using something like an `ExecutorCompletionService` or fork/join, he's allocating an executor each time the thread runs.

Comment: Keep in mind that once an executor is terminated, it will no longer accept jobs, so it's not like he can reuse it. He _has_ to create a new one each time to work like he says. It's basically a poor implementation of fork/join.

Comment: @Brian OK, I see I misunderstood you comment (English is not my native language). Another question is, you didn't explain what is the point to use your homemade threads instead of standard ones. Did you mean to replace the run() method as yonran supposed?

Comment: That's okay :) And no I didn't, sorry. That was my fault. I'll update my answer to reflect that.